# Reusing a register form as an edit form Angular 9

Tags: angular, forms, frontend, reusability

I am building a web page with authentication and authorization in Angular 9. This is the first bigger project I am building in Angular som bear with me. I have built a Register-component that I would like to reuse as an edit-component. The problem is that the password is required in the formfield (I am using Angular Material). But it should only be shown and the password only required when the form is used as a register-form not a edit-form. Any suggestions dear friends?

Here is the controller:

```
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
 import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth.service';
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 import { User } from '../user';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-edit',
 templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss'],
 })
 export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
 userForm: FormGroup;
 pageTitle: string;
 errorMessage: string;
 loading: false;
 user: User;
 private sub: Subscription;

 constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  role: [''],
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  email: [
    '',
    [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(1)],
  ],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
  });

  this.sub = this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
  const workId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  console.log('ID FROM REGISTER', workId);
  this.getUser(workId);
  });
  }
 getUser(id) {
  console.log('WAS IN GET USER', id);
   if (id) {
  this.authService.getUserProfile(id).subscribe({
    next: (user: User) => {
      console.log('USER', user);
      this.displayUser(user);
    },
       error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
     });
     } else {
      this.pageTitle = 'Register';
     }
     }
    displayUser(user: User): void {
    if (this.userForm) {
     this.userForm.reset();
    }

     this.user = user;
    console.log('USER', this.user);

    this.pageTitle = `Edit User: ${this.user.firstName} ${this.user.lastName}`;

   this.userForm.patchValue({
   role: this.user.role,
   firstName: this.user.firstName,
   lastName: this.user.lastName,
   email: this.user.email,
   date: this.user.date,
   password: this.user.password,
   });
   }

  get f() {
   return this.userForm.controls;
  }

  saveUser(): void {
    if (this.userForm.valid) {
     if (this.userForm.dirty) {
    const u = { ...this.user, ...this.userForm.value };

    if (u._id === null) {
      this.registerUser();
    } else {
      this.updateUser(u._id);
    }
    }
    }
    }
    updateUser(id: any) {
    console.log('UPDATING', this.userForm.value);
    this.authService.updateUser(this.userForm.value).subscribe((res) => {});
    this.userForm.reset();
    this.router.navigate(['users']);
    }

    registerUser() {
    console.log(this.userForm.value);

    this.authService.register(this.userForm.value).subscribe((res) => {});
    this.userForm.reset();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
    }
```

And here is the template:

```
<div class="mat-typography">
<div class="mat-title">{{ pageTitle }}</div>
</div>
<form class="form" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="user && user._id !== undefined">
<mat-label>Role</mat-label>
<input
  matInput
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="role"
  placeholder="Role"
 />
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
 <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
  <input
  matInput
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="firstName"
  placeholder="Enter first name"
  required
  />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
  <input
  matInput
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="lastName"
  placeholder="Enter last name"
  required
 />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Email address</mat-label>
  <input
  matInput
  type="email"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="email"
  placeholder="Enter email"
  required
  />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <input
  matInput
  type="password"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="password"
  placeholder="Password"
  required
  />
</mat-form-field>
<button type="submit" mat-button-flat>Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add validation and delete validation by using `this.userForm.get('password').setValidators('your new validator or null')` and next step you need to update the form validators by using `this.userForm.updateValueAndValidity()`